# Sentient tapeworm takes over father's mind?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking  for a short story where a youngish person is sent on a galactic mission by their father, whose body is being taken over by a kind of "super tapeworm". I would have read it in F&SF or Analog magazine circa 2010 (+/- 5 years). IIRC, as these tapeworms grow, they merge their appearance with the host, in addition to slowly dominating the host's will. Horrifying stuff!

It felt like the story was part of a series - i.e., it alluded to a lot of background, and didn't resolve much. Again, "if I recall correctly"! I think the first part took place on Earth, and the child is sent to gather information/allies/McGuffins on some world that's a center for diplomacy or learning... something like that.